# Which one to use for WebService call- HttpURLConnection or DefaultHttpClient?

Tags: android, web-services, httpurlconnection

I have used only DefaultHttpClient for WebService call in my apps.
But as DefaultHttpClient is deprecated i am confused that what to use.
I want to choose the best among them for my further development.
Also suggest me if any other best way to call WebServices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Android have deprecated `DefaultHTTPClient` Class and methods.
Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher, use the `HttpURLConnection` class instead. This API is more efficient because it reduces network use through transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption.
To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Here is URL from where you can have more details about HttpURLConnection.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 2):

DefaultHttpClient is kind of Apache Library that still used but nowadays, HttpURLConnection borns and it's recommend by google because it's more suitable for mobile application than Apache Library. DefaultHttpClient also can be used out of android environment, but in android, it's deprecated and we should use HttpUrlConnection with many advantages: good for limit android memory, good for battery ...
It would find it not too difficult to use, below is some pieces of code that can be useful

```
 URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIME_OUT);
    connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIME_OUT);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=" + CHARSET);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParams.getBytes().length));
    if (headers != null) addHeaderFields(connection, headers);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(urlParams)) {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), CHARSET), true);
        writer.append(urlParams);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    // checks server's status code first
    int status = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        connection.disconnect();
    } else {
        throw new ApiException(ApiException.APP_EXCEPTION, "Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
    }
    return response.toString();
```

Comment: If i use
     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=" + CHARSET); then i cant get output. Without this request property its working.

Answer (score 0):

DefaultHTTPClient is deprecated in android and will no longer be supported in Marshmallow (Android 6.0) and the API's after it. HTTPURLConnection is preferred over HTTPClient.

For networking operations I would recommend you to use Volley , Android's official networking related well tuned library. It eases the way network calls are made and is faster plus it's operations are asynchronous by default (you don't need to worry about custom threads for network calls).

Here is a good tutorial to use Volley : [Android working with Volley Library](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Android guide for Volley : [Transmitting Network Data Using Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. But if we exclude networking then HTTPURLConnection is better option to communicate with Server.

Comment: Networking comprises everything, communication with server , sending POST/GET requests , receiving response from server , everything is networking . :)
If you use Volley you wouldn't have to write tons of code for communicating with server.